# DFA which visit a specific state at least once

Tags: automata, finite-automata

Given a DFA M that satisfies language A, how do I modify M such that a new language B consisting of all strings that are accepted by M and cause M to enter a specific state r at least once are satisfied by the modified DFA?

I try to remember whether state r is visited or not. But as I known, unlike turing machine, DFA does not have any memory.

Comment: The memory of a FSA is called a *state*. You can add (a finite amount of) information there.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the "have seen $r$" information as follows.

Based on the old DFA $A = (Q, \Sigma, \delta, q_0,F)$ construct a new one $A' = (Q', \Sigma, \delta', q'_0,F')$. State set of $A'$ equals $Q'=Q\times \{0,1\}$, which adds a bit to the original states.

In each step you mave along just like the original automaton, except when entering state $r$ when we set the bit to $1$.

Initial state $(q_0,0)$: initial, not seen $r$. Final states $F' = F \times\{1\}$: final *and* seen $r$.

Answer (score 0):

You can break the problem down into two parts: strings that make it to state $r$, and strings that, starting at $r$, make it to an accepting state.

To get a DFA $M'$ for the first one, we take $M$, make all the accept states non-accepting, and make $r$ an accept state, call this state $r_{M'}$. So $M'$ accepts all strings that finish at $r$.

Then we can make  a second DFA $M''$ that accepts all strings that start at $r$ and reach an accepting state of $M$. Take $M$, and make $r$ the start state instead of whichever state was the original starting state, call this state $r_{M''}$.

We can then use the concatenation construction to get a DFA for $L(M') \circ L(M'')$, which is all strings which go from the start state to $r$, then to an accept state. To do this we take $M'$, remove $r_{M'}$'s accept status, take $M''$, and make $r_{M''}$ no longer a start state, then add an $\varepsilon$-transition from $r_{M'}$ to $r_{M''}$. This gives an NFA, which we can then turn into a DFA in the usual manner. In this case we can shortcut this just by identifying $r_{M'}$ and $r_{M''}$ (i.e. joining the two DFAs at those states).